# How do you verify integrity of data passed through AWS SQS using C# SDK?

Tags: c#, sdk, amazon-web-services, md5, amazon-sqs

First off, does the AWS C# SDK self check itself? Right now, I have code that does stuff like

**md5 checking**

```
List<string> msgs = new List<string>();
ReceiveMessageResponse response = this.getMessageRoutine(num);
foreach (Message m in response.ReceiveMessageResult.Message) {
   if (m.MD5OfBody.ToUpper() != Global.StringFunctions.CalculateMD5Hash(m.Body)) {
       throw new Exception("TODO IMPLEMENT: RECEIVED MESSAGE IS CORRUPT");
   }
       msgs.Add(m.Body);
}
return msgs;
```

**verifying that the user defined IDs sent out came back in the response**, and that the md5 the server generated of the message matches the message sent

```
            foreach (SendMessageBatchResultEntry e in response.SendMessageBatchResult.SendMessageBatchResultEntry) {

                foreach (SendMessageBatchRequestEntry r in entry) {
                    if (r.Id == e.Id) {
                        if (Global.StringFunctions.CalculateMD5Hash(r.MessageBody) != e.MD5OfMessageBody.ToUpper()) {
                            throw new Exception("TODO IMPLEMENT THIS: MD5 MISMATCH BETWEEN AWS:LOCAL (" + e.MD5OfMessageBody.ToUpper() + " : " + Global.StringFunctions.CalculateMD5Hash(r.MessageBody)+")");
                        }
                        entry.Remove(r);
                        break;
                    }
                    throw new Exception("TODO IMPLEMENT THIS: INVALID ID IN RESPONSE");
                }
            }
            if (entry.Count != 0) {
                throw new Exception("TODO IMPLEMENT: NOT ALL MESSAGES SENT HAD A CORRESPONDING CALLBACK");
            }
```

Is there a better implementation of something like this already created, something like
request.checkResponse(response) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent version of the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) ([1.5.23](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/.NET/9817131091441120)) includes the MD5 hash check as part of sending a single message, sending a batch of messages, and receiving messages. If that does not work for you, we would love to hear why and how we could make it better.

Thanks!